# How to decorate class functions with flask-socketio if the socketIO instance is a class member variable?

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I'm trying to create a hello world example for a flask application with socketio, that is wrapped into a class.

I want to wrap the whole application into a class, that can be embedded into other applications. For this purpose, I am creating the Flask application in the constructor of my class, and also create the SocketIO instance as a member too. 
The problem is that I get a NameError exception tellimg me that 'socketio' is not defined.

I have tried to adapt the minimum working example from : the flask-socketio tutorial (https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Here is the example code I'm trying to get to work:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

class ApplicationExample:

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.socketio = SocketIO(self.app)

    @socketio.on('ping')
    def pongResponse(self, message):
        emit('pong')

    def run(self):
        self.socketio.run(service.app, host='0.0.0.0')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    service = ApplicationExample()
    service.run()
```

I would like to bind the pongResponse function to the socketio instance inside my class. How is it possible to decorate the function while having the SocketIO class as a member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation you can use the below instead of a decorator

```py
def my_function_handler(data):
    pass

socketio.on_event('my event', my_function_handler, namespace='/test')
```

Which would become something like

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

class ApplicationExample:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.socketio = SocketIO(self.app)
        self.socketio.on_event('ping', self.pongResponse, namespace='/test')

    def pongResponse(self, message):
        emit('pong')

    def run(self):
        self.socketio.run(service.app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 2):

Since decorating a function simply calls the decorator and passes the decorated function as the first argument you can write:

```
def __init__(self):
    ... 
    self.pongResponse = self.socketio.on('ping')(self._pongResponse)

def _pongResponse(self, message):
    ...
```

A method beginning with a `_` denotes that is not part of the public API of the class (thus this simply is a convention). Also note that in python you should use `snake_case`instead of `camelCase` to name your functions and variables, although this is also just a convention.